# Spacing in cell with \makecell command

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn, makecell

I'm having a problem with deleting the extra space in the cell. I think it may have something to do with using `\makecell` in a `\mulitcolumn`. I'm trying to have empty space on the 1st line in the second column then have the other 2 values on two different lines.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\scriptsize
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Frequency} & {\textbf{Percentage}} \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|p{8em}|}{ Binge Drinker  \newline  Not Binge Drinker \newline Binge Drinker} & {\makecell{ \\ \\ 1147 \\ 2982}} & { \makecell{\\ \\  27.8 \\ 72.2}} \\
```

This is the table should look like with no extra in the cell.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\scriptsize
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{6em}|l|r|r }
 \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Independent Variable}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|} 
{\textbf{Chi- Square Results}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \textbf{Alcohol Use} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6em}|} 
 {\textbf{Chi-Square}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4em}|}{\textbf{P-Value}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{1em}|}{\textbf{Sig}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{8em}|}{Education\newline Freshman\newline 
 Sophomore/Junior\newline Senior/Grad} & -----\newline 71.9 \newline 73 
 \newline 71.2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-0.005} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.725} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
 \end{tabular}%
 \end{adjustbox}
 \caption{\textbf{Table 4.3.1}}
 \end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, please add a full compilable MWE that shows your problem and don't forget to indent the code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to have understood exactly what you want, but maybe it is this, obtained with `tabulatx`. Don't use  `adjustbox` with tables – it results in inconsistent font sizes:

```
\documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, caption, threeparttable, tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|c|}
 \hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Frequency} & {\textbf{Percentage}} \\
\hline
Binge Drinker & & \\
 Not Binge Drinker & 1147 & 27.8 \\
Binge Drinker & 2982 & 72.2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

table isbased on guessing ...since you not provide mwe. in above table design i use the `\thead` macro from the `makecell` package, and for vertical spacing of cells' contents in the second and third column `\multirow` cells. the code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
    \hline
\thead{Variable}
    & \thead{Frequency} & \thead{Percentage}        \\
    \hline
\makecell[tl]{Binge Drinker\\
              Not Binge Drinker\\
              Binge Drinker}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{1147\\ 2982}}
        & \multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{27.8\\ 72.2}}   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
it seems that my guessing in the first attempt wass wrong, hopefully i will have now more luck :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}

\begin{document}
{\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
    \hline
\thead{Variable}        & \thead{Frequency}         & \thead{Percentage}        \\
    \hline
Binge Drinker           &                           &                           \\
Not Binge Drinker       & \makecell{1147\\ 2982}    & \makecell{27.8\\ 72.2}    \\
Binge Drinker           &                           &                           \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

or like this:

[image]

where table body is:

```
   \begin{tabular}{|p{11em}|c|c|}
    \hline
\thead{Variable}        & \thead{Frequency}         & \thead{Percentage}        \\
    \hline
Binge Drinker           &                           &                           \\
    \hline
Not Binge Drinker       & \makecell{1147\\ 2982}    & \makecell{27.8\\ 72.2}    \\
    \hline
Binge Drinker           &                           &                           \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: My question is there any way to have Not Binge Drinker to be aligned with 1147 and 27.8?

Comment: sorry, this is no clear from your question ... how should be aligned? numbers are in two lines ...

Comment: \documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}     begin{table}[!htbp]
  \scriptsize
   \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{r|p{6em}|l|r|r }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Independent Variable}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Chi- Square Results}} \\
    \hline

Comment: please, edit your question and put above code there!

Comment: @Zarko Dearest when I see a response from the style I immediately understand that the user is you. Apparently you like the tables very much :-). Greetings.